# How can I test for when an Azure Storage Account network rule has actually taken effect

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-storage-account

I have a pipeline that will whitelist the agents current IP to a storage account's network rules with:

```
az storage account network-rule add
```

It then immediately moves to the next task which requires access within one of the storage account's containers. Because there is a 5-30 second period where the network rule is taking effect, the task needs retry logic because it almost always returns:

```
autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation
```

After enough time and retries have passed, then task will then happily continue. I was wondering if there was a recommended method for writing a loop that tests access to the container and only exits the loop when the firewall rule has actually been applied.

Comment: In my case, I am using ```Start-Sleep -Seconds 60``` after IP is added to the NW rule. I think a while loop can be used with Start-Sleep until an action becomes true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> How can I test for when an Azure Storage Account network rule has actually taken effect

You can use the below powershell command to tests access to the container after network rule applied.

**Command:**

```
$storageAccountName = ""
$resourceGroupName = ""
$containerName = ""
$currentIP = ""
$storageAccountKey=""
 # Add the current IP to the network rule
az storage account network-rule add --resource-group $resourceGroupName --account-name $storageAccountName --ip-address $currentIP

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

 # Wait for the network rule to take effect
while ($true)
{
    # Test access to the container
    try {
        Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context (New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey)
# If the access is successful, exit the loop
       break
    }
    catch {
        # Wait for 10 seconds before trying again
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: that was what I was looking for, however I needed to add -ErrorAction Stop in order to hit the catch block when it fails